# Multi Column Header for Angular 2 Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I am try to create a Kendo Grid with multi column header using Kendo UI for Angular 2. Previously, the old version for Kendo supported this (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/multicolumnheaders). Is this supported in the Kendo Grid for Angular 2?

Another thing that I am trying is column filtering capability which was enabled using the columnMenu option previously. Is this option present in the Kendo Grid for Angular 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are part of the future plans of the framework, note that Kendo UI for Angular 2 is a completely new product built from scratch and you can keep track on the roadmap here:

http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap

Comment: @ken check my answer below, if you haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

The feature is now implemented.

You need to use the `<kendo-grid-column-group>`

Here is a plunker from KendoUI  http://plnkr.co/edit/mPbo8CRYYm2AcdGdEfrY?p=preview

Source:  http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/#toc-multi-column-headers

Comment: Thanks @alicona !!

Comment: I fixed the link @Mr_Perfect